# Implicit casting VARCHAR to VARBINARY is not allowed

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I'm stuck with a problem. I'm developing a ASP.net MVC application that manages file uploads to a DB. Not that big of a deal. But every time I execute my SQL-Command, he tells me that I need to convert to VARBINARY first.

That problem is asked a lot here and on the Internet, but I still can't get it working..

That's what I got:

The SQL table:

```
DocID               INT             IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
DocName             VARCHAR(512)    NOT NULL,
DocData             VARBINARY(max)  NOT NULL,
ContentType         NVARCHAR(100)   NOT NULL,
ContentLength       BIGINT          NOT NULL,
InsertionDate       DATETIME        NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),                     
CONSTRAINT PK_DOC_STORE PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (DocID)
```

Read the file to a byte[] with BinaryReader.

```
var reader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream);
var data = reader.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);
```

And the INSERT INTO C# code:

```
sqlConnection.Open();

var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand
(
"INSERT INTO DocStore VALUES ('@DocumentName', '@DocumentData', '@DocumentType', '@DocumentSize', '@DocumentDate')"
, sqlConnection
);

sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocumentName", file.FileName);
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocumentData", data);
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocumentType", file.ContentType);
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocumentSize", file.ContentLength);
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocumentDate", DateTime.Now);

var success = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

sqlConnection.Close();
```

What's wrong here? I can't see the problem.. Shouldn't the byte[] work in a parameterized command string like this for the VARBINARY part?

Comment: Have you considered the use of a `FILESTREAM` column to hold your binary file data? The `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlFileStream` class can write stream data directly and it would simplify your whole process.

Comment: Isn't `FileStream`only available on Sql Server 2012+?

Comment: @Pikoh: FILESTREAM is available starting with SQL2008.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean well..maybe in your sql2008. In mine (i've just tried) does not accept a FILESTREAM column...

Comment: @Pikoh: FILETABLE was introduced by SQL2012.

Comment: @Pikoh: Maybe that server isn't SQL2008+ or maybe that database has a lower compatibility level.

Comment: @Pikoh you have to enable it at the server level before you can use it, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645923(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Ok you two are right...but you have to enable it before it works. My bad,sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

Instead of

```
var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand
(
"INSERT INTO DocStore VALUES ('@DocumentName', '@DocumentData', '@DocumentType', '@DocumentSize', '@DocumentDate')"
, sqlConnection
);
```

I would use

```
var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand
(
"INSERT INTO DocStore VALUES (@DocumentName, @DocumentData, @DocumentType, @DocumentSize, @DocumentDate)"
, sqlConnection
);
```

**Why ?**

Because `"INSERT INTO ...  '@DocumentData' ... "` string contain a T-SQL statement. Within T-SQL, single quotes (`'bla'`) are used to delimit the start and the end of string constant and also, in some cases, it can be used for column delimiters. So `'@DocumentData'` represents a string / `VARCHAR` constant from the point of view of SQL Server. In this case, it tries to do an **implicit conversion** of `VARCHAR` values (`'@D...'`) to `VARBINARY` (data type of `DocData` colum; first column is skipped because it has `IDENTITY` property).  But according to 
[image] between `VARCHAR` and `VARBINARY` are allowed only explicit conversions.

Note: as a best practice I would explicit define the list of target columns for `INSERT` statement.

Comment: Can you explain how that would fix the problem?

Answer (score 5):

You put quotes around parameter names, which will make them string literals.

Also, I would suggest to specify the columns in the `insert` statement. If you don't specify the columns to insert on, it takes the exact definition from your table (excluding the ID field since it is auto incremented). It is possible to break your query if you insert a field in between.

```
INSERT INTO DocStore (DocName, DocData, ContentType, ContentLength, InsertionDate)
VALUES (@DocumentName, @DocumentData, @DocumentType, @DocumentSize, @DocumentDate)
```

Comment: Can you explain why? If the id column is an auto increment, you dont need to specify each column, assuming you are inserting data into all columns

Comment: That is how SQL works: if you don't supply the field names, you have to give the values in order of appearance. That includes auto-increment fields.

Comment: I'm going to challenge that. I have a table with 3 columns, the first is autoincrement. If i do `INSERT INTO Table VALUES ('col1','col2')` The statement executes correctly and inserts the data. (where col1 is actually the second column of the table)

Comment: That is true. I mixed up Oracle and SQL Server. Updated the answer already.

Comment: @Takarii There's plenty of other questions on SO that were answered by "use a column list", including one I answered. It does seem to work in 2012 R2, but I have no idea when it became possible to omit auto-incremented fields. And it still doesn't work with fields that have defaults - e.g. row guids. Regardless, it's still generally a bad idea to omit the column list :)

Comment: I must agree with @Luaan. Works or not, i think it's better to always specify the list of columns to avoid a lot of issues

Comment: The cause of that error/exception isn't the missing of column names. It's the usage of `'@singlequotes'` around variable' names.

Comment: @Luaan I expect it is because the autoincrement is server assigned rather than user assigned. Like you, i too don't know when this started to work - However I have noticed it for the better part of a decade to be true at the very least.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean Well, that's the very first sentence in this answer :)

Comment: @Luaan: The missing of colums' names isn't the cause of this error. This is a secondary topic.